# I need captcha implemtation for any custom form in wordpress

Tags: captcha

need captcha implementation for any existing custom form in wordpress. I have already a form in my plugin where I need one captcha to be added. Please let me know the procedure to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can implement a security captcha image into our own plugin using [Really Simple Captcha](https://wordpress.org/plugins/really-simple-captcha/) plugin. See the example explained in the following link, how to use the Really Simple Captcha Plugin with our own WordPress plugin [Implementation of captcha image into your own plugin using Really Simple Captcha plugin](http://sabitas.wordpress.com/2014/09/21/implementation-of-captcha-image-into-yur-own-plugin-using-really-simple-captcha-plugin/).

Comment: Answers should be [more than plain links](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). They should actually be an answer instead of a route where someone will _maybe find_ an answer. Please help preventing link rot, [edit] your answer and provide the needed information that helps the OP as well as later visitors to solve their problem.